# Trying to create a file in Python, but get permission error instead

Tags: python, pycharm, python-os

I am trying to create a dictionary and a file, if not exist.

```
fp = os.path.dirname(__file__)   

def create_dir_file():
try:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(fp, 'data'))
    try:
        open('movies.txt', 'w+').close()
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
except FileExistsError:
    pass
```

2 weeks ago, I used this code for a different project and it worked. Although not changing anything, 2 weeks later this code does not work anymore and I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: You aren't specifying any directory for the file, so the difference is that when it worked, the current working directory was someplace that you could write files, and now it's someplace you can't (inside Program Files, perhaps).  What was the point of calling `os.makedirs()`, and then not using the created directory to store the file?

Comment: You are NOT specifying any directory in the `open()` call, which is where it matters.

Comment: Youp, you are right. \n open(os.path.join(fp, 'data') + '/movies.txt', 'w+').close() \n should be the correct way

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).